# Graph ~ axis alignment issue

Tags: d3.js

I'm currently working on a quite basic graph using 2 ordinal axes. X axis shows 4 categories, Y axis shows 3. For some reason, the plotted circles don't align with the plotted axes.
An example can be seen at http://jsfiddle.net/SrdY6/. Problem seems to be translation-related, but the only translation in there is applied to the large containing `<g>` element:

```
var lunchgraph = svg.append("g")
    .attr("class", "lunchgraph")
    .attr("transform", "translate(" + lunchmargin.left + "," + lunchmargin.top + ")");
```

I've been looking at this for some time now, but can't spot where things go wrong... Anyone with more insight?

Answer (score 1):

Nothing like putting a question out there and risking public shame, only to find out the answer within minutes after posting.

For ordinal axes configured with `rangeBands` or `rangeRoundBands`, the scale function returns the lower value of the given input. To have the plot align with the exact categorical labels, you need to add half of the `rangeBand` to the calculated coordinate.

So: no problem with the translations or anything, but with the computation of `cx` and `cy` coordinates for placing the circles in the graph.

Correct code:

```
    .attr("cx", function(d) { return x(d.label) + x.rangeBand()/2 ;} )
    .attr("cy", function(d) { return y(d.sqid) + y.rangeBand()/2 ; } )
```